# How to display popup with html in firefox bootstrapped extensions?

Tags: firefox, popup, firefox-addon

I developed a firefox bootstrapped extension (without add-on sdk). I need to display a popup with html content, something like panel in add-on sdk. Also, it is necessary that the extension could interact with content in the popup. Also, I need a way to display html content in separate tab and interact with this content.   So what can I use to implement what I need?

Comment: those are several separate questions. also, what research have you done so far?

Comment: I check source code of add-on sdk panel https://github.com/mozilla/addon-sdk/blob/master/lib/sdk/panel.js. As I discovered, it uses xul panel. I figured out how to display html content, but I can not understand how it is possible to implement the interaction between expansion and content inside the panel.

Answer (score 0):

You can append an iframe to that panel, and then load a page into that iframe. That's what I did in this simple addon here - https://github.com/Noitidart/AwesomeBar-Power-Tip/

Here's another gist that does something similar - https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/9445992

I think this is how the SDK does it as well.

Answer (score 0):

> but I can not understand how it is possible to implement the interaction between expansion and content inside the panel.

The panel or its `frameLoader` property should have a `messageManager`, which can be used to [load frame scripts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Multiprocess_Firefox/Message_Manager/Message_manager_overview) and pass messages to them.